# Can't Compile Compil32.dproj using Delphi 10.1

Tags: delphi, inno-setup

**Hello I want to recompile Inno Setup Compiler's source code to rename the Uninstall Executable Generation like `unins***.exe.`**

*When I try to compile, Delphi says that `Error Reading Form : Class not found` because my Delphi IDE haven't all the packages needed to compile `Compil32.exe.`*

[image: This is Very Annoying Problem.]

If I compile my `Compil32.exe` without all missing classes and run it, `Compil32.exe has stopped working` appears as it isn't correctly compiled.

Please tell me what version of Delphi or what IDE Packages want to be downloaded and can be used to compile / build `Compil32.exe` without any problem.

*Thanks in Advance.*

Comment: Obviously you should install the missing component(s) first. I have no idea where you can find them, but I assume they are in the source code too, somewhere.

Comment: The `READ ME` file [in the repository](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc) explains exactly what you need to do.  That's why it's called "READ ME" - it's the first thing you always need to do.

Comment: @J... pah. Real men never read manuals. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  Yeah, but they never stop to ask for directions either. ;)

Comment: Perhaps on the road, but on S.O. that is a little different. <g>

Comment: Okay I follow readme and try again :( Oh....my rep is lowering..... :(

Comment: JR Software says they compile Inno Setup Compiler with Delphi 2009 and Update 3...........So is that the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit confusing.

**Readme does say you need to install components**
The [readme.md](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/README.md) address this issue.

Let me quote it for you

> 3. Component Installation
>
> If you intend to view or modify the Setup project's forms, you must install the following component units, which can be found in the Components directory.
>
> ```
>     BidiCtrls
>     BitmapImage
>     FolderTreeView
>     NewCheckListBox
>     NewNotebookReg
>     NewProgressBar
>     NewStaticText
>     PasswordEdit
>     RichEditViewer
> ```
>
> If you intend to view or modify the Compil32 project's forms, you must additionally install the following components. (Like the Compil32 project itself, these require Delphi 3 or later.)
>
> ```
>     DropListBox
>     NewTabSet
> ```

**But the readme does not tell you how to do this**

The readme assumes you know how to install components from scratch.
This is a bit of an assumption and I can see why you're getting stuck here.

In Delphi you need a create a `.dpk` (package) file to put your components in.
Choose `File->New->Package`
And add all of the units listed above to your package.
Now `build` the package and then `install` it.
You should be seeing a message that 11 new components have been installed.

If this is successful you can open the forms.
If you have previously `ignored` any errors and saved the project Delphi will have removed the components. In that case you'll need to reload the project from github.

Comment: Thank You Very Much.........Solved the Problem and I successfully compiled `Compil32.exe`. But I still can't compile `Setup.exe` in Inno Setup Source Code Folder.`Could not find unit UpsUtils.pas`............

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the Install VCL Components wizard, which is part of every IDE from XE on. This will create or load a package for you and even install everything.

Comment: @flavalee, that probably because .... it cannot find that unit. Check to see where the unit is located and if that path is included in the search path for the project. `Project->Options->Delphi compiler (first option) >>>> Search Path`

Comment: I know that `Setup.e32` as an Inno Setup Compiler's file but the Delphi shows it as `Setup.exe` not `e32` when I open `Setup.dproj`.Why that?